# Change row background color depending on cell value vba

Tags: vba, excel

i want to change the row background color if the date is today ( the dates are in column A starting with A7 ) but it doesn't work. Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

```
Sub Update_Row_Colors()
   Dim LRow As Integer
   Dim LCell As String
   Dim LColorCells As String
   LRow = 7
   While LRow < 50
      LCell = "A" & LRow
      'Color will changed in columns A to AM
      LColorCells = "A" & LRow & ":" & "AM" & LRow
      Select Case Left(Range(LCell).Value, 6)
         Case Now
            Range(LColorCells).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            Range(LColorCells).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
         Case Else
            Rows(LRow & ":" & LRow).Select
            Range(LColorCells).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
          End Select
          LRow = LRow + 1
   Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: at you give a sample of your data found in the A Column please?

Comment: Any reason you're not simply using Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I don't use Conditional Formatting because i don't know how many rows column A will have at the end of the year. Column A has the dates of the year - they can be duplicated A10 to A 20 can contain 08.01.2016 .

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of the worksheet looks like but I'd still assume you could apply conditional formatting to the column. The formatting would still only affect non-blank cells that match the conditions you set.

Comment: Otherwise use the Immediate window to display a few values as you step through to ensure the match is occuring as expected. You might need to use CDate().

Comment: Actually. If you have "08.01.2016" Excel will usually not recognise that as an acutal date. Try CDate(Replace(Left(Range(LCell).Value, 6),".","-")) and Case Date(). Another handy tip is to try ?TypeName(something) to check what data type Excel thinks somehting is

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you use Now, which returns the current datetime, whilst you're trying to compare this to a date. Try changing:

```
Case Now
```

To

```
Case Date()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to compare the dates from Column A with the current date and if the dates are the current date turn the row light blue.

Comment: The function Date() will give you the current date. The difference between the two is that Now will return `01-01-2001 10:00:00` and Date() returns `01-01-2001`

Answer (score 1):

You can use date as @Wouter mentioned.

You also need to change your `Left(Range(LCell).Value, 6)` to `Left(Range(LCell).Value, 10)`

If you want to use `Now` then you need to use the `Left` function as well to remove the time from the `Now` value.

See below for working answer.

Also remember to always use `Long` when you want to dimension a variable for referencing a `Row` or `Column`

```
 Sub Update_Row_Colors()

      'Always want to use a long for referencing a Row or Column
      Dim LRow As Long
      Dim LCell As String
      Dim LColorCells As String

      LRow = 7

      While LRow < 50

           LCell = "A" & LRow
           'Color will changed in columns A to AM
           LColorCells = "A" & LRow & ":" & "AM" & LRow

           Select Case Left(Range(LCell).Value, 10)
           Case Left(Now, 10)
                Range(LColorCells).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
                Range(LColorCells).Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
           Case Else
                Rows(LRow & ":" & LRow).Select
                Range(LColorCells).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
           End Select

           LRow = LRow + 1
      Wend
 End Sub
```

Just a extra piece of info, you can shorten/clean you code just by using `Range`better, see below.

I have included a line to check the used rows, note that even if there is a space " " in the `Row` is will count it.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub Update_Row_Colors()

      Dim LRow As Long
      Dim RowRange As Range

      Dim LastRow As Long
      LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

      For LRow = 7 To LastRow

           Set RowRange = Range(Cells(LRow, "A"), Cells(LRow, "AM"))

           If Left(Cells(LRow, "A").Value, 10) = Left(Now, 10) Then
                RowRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
                RowRange.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
           Else
                RowRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
           End If

      Next LRow
 End Sub
```